# Inconsistent search results using fuzzy search across multiple collections

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search, edismax

I'm building a search query using the edismax parser and specifying the query fields. Sometimes I need to search across multiple collections and sometimes I am just searching against a single collection. In either case, I am generating a single query by specifying the `collections` parameter in addition to my query fields.

This means that my `qf` parameter may list fields that do not exist in one or more collections. Normally this isn't a problem and I get back the results I expect (provided I am using the edismax parser). However, I have noticed that if I perform a fuzzy search this way, I am getting inconsistent results.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/activity/select?q=jva040~2&defType=edismax&qf=Code
```

gives me results with Codes like

```
RVA010, JAA048, RVA041
```

but if I issue a query with a non-existent field in the activity collection like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/activity/select?q=jva040~2&defType=edismax&qf=Code+Poop
```

I get results with Codes like

```
53721ILTHRS-CHFSPMT-2, 53721ILTHRS-CHFSCOS-2, 53721ILTHRS-CHFSNEO--11/2/15
```

Is this a bug within Solr or am I constructing this query wrong? I am using Solr version 5.2.1

Comment: Have you tried with the debug option turned on? That will show you why solr returned what it returned. Also, use the analysis window under your core in the solr admin UI to see how your query is analyzed and matched to an indexed value.

Comment: Looking at the debug response, it seems when I specify an non-existent field, the tilde is treated as a space and the edit distance value is treated as a separate term to search.